# Convert Android code fragment from Java to C# ("inline class extension")

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to convert an Android Library from Java to C# (Xamarin).

Take a look at this definition of a private field in the class:

```
private SimpleOnGestureListener longClickListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        hasPerformedLongPress = childView.performLongClick();
        if (hasPerformedLongPress) {
            if (rippleHover) {
                startRipple(null);
            }
            cancelPressedEvent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        hasPerformedLongPress = false;
        return super.onDown(e);
    }
};
```

As far as I know there is no way in C# to create an "inline extension" of a class.

How would you convert this piece of code ? Keep in mind that "hasPerformedLongPress" and "rippleHover" are private fields of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new private class which implements the interface - you can access the fields of the outer class via the 'outerInstance' field of the inner class.  However, the only way I can make this work is to change the 'longClickListener' field to a local variable in order to be able to pass 'this' to the new private class constructor - since you can't use 'this' from a C# field definition:

```
internal class test
{
    private bool rippleHover;
    private bool hasPerformedLongPress;

    internal virtual void method()
    {
        SimpleOnGestureListener longClickListener = new SimpleOnGestureListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper(this);
    }

    private class SimpleOnGestureListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        private readonly test outerInstance;

        public SimpleOnGestureListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper(test outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }

        public virtual void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
        {
            outerInstance.hasPerformedLongPress = childView.performLongClick();
            if (outerInstance.hasPerformedLongPress)
            {
                if (outerInstance.rippleHover)
                {
                    startRipple(null);
                }
                cancelPressedEvent();
            }
        }

        public override bool onDown(MotionEvent e)
        {
            outerInstance.hasPerformedLongPress = false;
            return base.onDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought it is not possible to access private fields of the outer class?

Comment: I updated my answer - however it may not work out for you since I change the field to a local variable inside 'method'.  You should be able to monkey around with this to get what you want (change back to a field, but initialize it in a method?).